# Is there any way to do a gallery like Pinterest with display: flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was trying to understand how the CSS `display: flex` property works, and I can't find a way to do what I was trying: a photo/portfolio gallery like Pinterest, only using flexbox.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.Portifolio-container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-basis: 10;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.Portifolio-image {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.imagem {
    width: 296px;
    max-height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
}
.portifolio-name {
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    font-family: trebuchet;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="Portifolio-container">
    <div class="Portifolio-image">
        <img src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/HkjVzNs.jpg" class="imagem"></img>
        <div class="portifolio-name"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Portifolio-image">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/85/52/14/855214cc10e81dc3613f717c2d16d60b.jpg" class="imagem"></img>
        <div class="portifolio-name"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Portifolio-image">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/1d/62/94/1d6294ece94809441340c885feddd08a.jpg" class="imagem"></img>
        <div class="portifolio-name"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="Portifolio-image">
        <img src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/HkjVzNs.jpg" class="imagem"></img>
        <div class="portifolio-name"></div>
    </div>
      <div class="Portifolio-image">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/1d/62/94/1d6294ece94809441340c885feddd08a.jpg" class="imagem"></img>
        <div class="portifolio-name"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Portifolio-image">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/85/52/14/855214cc10e81dc3613f717c2d16d60b.jpg" class="imagem"></img>
        <div class="portifolio-name"></div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

I want the row to break after three images, but at the same time I want them to have only 20px of margin in the bottom of each image.

Comment: It *is* possible in CSS as far as I know, but Pinterest uses JavaScript for their layout. A popular library for that is Masonry.js.

Answer (score 7):

I fiddled around and this *is* possible with just CSS now, thanks to `column-width` and `column-gap` properties in the [CSS Multi-Column Layout Module Level 1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-multicol-1/) (wow, that was a mouthful). Most major browsers are still behind prefixes, *but* IE supports this unprefixed, even in IE10!

The bad news for you (I guess) is that this doesn't use `display: flex;` like you were hoping. I'm not sure it's possible with the Flexbox CSS module. *However*, you can visit the [Barbarian Meets Coding](http://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/barbaric-basics-web-development/css-layout-dist/flexbox-layout.html) site to see more demos of what's possible with Flexbox.

Here's a bare bones demo:

```css
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    -moz-column-width: 18em;
    -webkit-column-width: 18em;
    column-width: 18em;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap:1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
    margin: 5px;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">text saves lives, use it more! Or use it less; it's up to you, really</div>
    <div class="item">more text that makes stuff seem really, really long but really it doesn't say anything at all. Isn't that just the craziest thing?</div>
    <div class="item">even more text</div>
    <div class="item">text the fourth</div>
    <div class="item">The container contains things</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet oh forget this filler text, I'm tired of it!</div>
    <div class="item">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah h</div>
    <div class="item">More words to impress you</div>
    <div class="item">Content Content Content! Like Location Location Location in Real Estate, it's what's important on the web!</div>
    <div class="item">Derp</div>
</div>
```

Click Full Screen on the demo above and resize your browser to see it in action.

And here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kt91Lsd/) demo, as well.

Comment: Nice trick. However the divs will will column by column instead of filling row by row. Is there a way to do the same thing, row by row?

Comment: @LeonFreire I haven't worked with Flexbox in a little while, so I'm not sure if it can be done in that, but I know you can do this with the new CSS Grid layout that has landed in browsers recently.